# SQL Queries Processing order is not consistent

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Having two tables `products` and `product_types`, both have the following rows :

```
products
```

[image]

```
product_types
```

[image]

Executing the following query :

```
SELECT p.name, pt.name
FROM products p, product_types pt
WHERE p.product_type_id = 1;
```

yields the following result :

[image]

But executing this query :

```
SELECT p.name, pt.name
FROM products p, product_types pt
WHERE p.product_type_id = pt.product_type_id
OR p.product_type_id = 1;
```

yields the following result :

[image]

Normally, the SQL interpreter starts with one table and spans the other, what's the rule for that ? In the 1st query, it started with the `products` table and spanned `product_types`, but in the 2nd query, it started with the `product_types` table and spanned the `products` table (as can be seen from the order). Why is it not consistent, normally, I'd expect the result of the 2nd query to be something like this :

[image]

Why ? Does it choose the table to start with randomly or what ?

NOTE: Don't mind the queries, it may not make much sense, I'm only interested in the order of the results.

Comment: The rule is that the order of the results are indeterminate unless your query has an `ORDER BY` for the outer-most `SELECT`.  Period.  Even the same query run multiple times can return results in different orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it choose the table to start with randomly or what ?

It may appear random, but it's not. It's just that the query optimizer is free to consider different ways of executing the query, and to pick the execution plan it feels will return the expected results (as defined by the query) in the most optimal way.

Even the slightest change to the definition of a query may cause the optimizer to consider a different execution plan to be more efficient. And even when executing the same query multiple times, it may pick different execution plans at different times if, for instance, the distribution of the data in the different tables involved has changed (and that's just one of many possible reasons).

The fact that it can pick whatever execution plan is optimal in a given situation will, of course, impact the order of the rows that are returned. And that is well within the rights of what the query optimizer can do, because ***you did not request an explicit result order by including an `ORDER BY` clause in your query.*** The only way that you can guarantee consistent ordering of results is by explicitly requesting that order via an `ORDER BY` clause. Don't let anyone tell you otherwise, they're lying.

Answer (score 4):

You have a complete misunderstanding of how SQL works.

SQL queries represent the *results* of data processing from a relational database.  They do *not* represent the steps taken.  A SQL query is processed in basically three steps:

1. The query is parsed.
2. The parsed result generates an optimized execution plan.
3. The SQL engine executes the result.

You state:

> Normally, the SQL interpreter starts with one table and spans the other, what's the rule for that ?

This is far, far from the truth.

The truth is that SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  They have no ordering.  Perhaps you should repeat that 50 times.  Two result sets in different orders are the same thing.

SQL *does* support the `ORDER BY` clause because ordering can be important.  This is how you get the results in a specified order.

Also, I would strongly advise you to stop using commas in the `FROM` clause.  This is a very archaic way of representing joins.  The correct way is to use the explicit `JOIN` keyword with the conditions in an `ON` clause -- something that has been part of the SQL standard for over 2 decades.